# @RestController not found, if main class not in top level package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class `Resource` annotated with `@RestController`, but it is only used if the main class `App` annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` is in the top level package.

Works:

```
com
 +- test
     +- project
         +- App.java
         |
         +- resources
         |   +- Resource.java
```

Does not work:

```
com
 +- test
     +- project
         +- app
         |   +- App.java
         |
         +- resources
         |   +- Resource.java
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. You should know it is equivalent to using @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan.

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)

> **ComponentScan** configures component scanning directives for use with
>   @Configuration classes. Provides support parallel with Spring XML's
>    element.
>
> One of basePackageClasses(), basePackages() or its alias value() may
>   be specified to define specific packages to scan. **If specific packages
>   are not defined scanning will occur from the package of the class with
>   this annotation.**

You went with the default settings, therefore your scanning takes place in the package of the class with the annotation.

You can either move it as you did, or specify basePackages in @ComponentScan.

Comment: Thanks. I added `@ComponentScan("com.test.project")`, which helped. But using root package now, as recommended in the Spring documentation, as suggested by @Predrag

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) you can find it is recommended to keep the main class above all other classes, to avoid having do use `basePackage`

> We generally recommend that you locate your main application class in a root package above other classes. The `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation is often placed on your main class, and it implicitly defines a base “search package” for certain items.
>   ...
>   Using a root package also allows the `@ComponentScan` annotation to be used without needing to specify a `basePackage` attribute. You can also use the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation if your main class is in the root package.